# Best way to introduce repeated action to a Button descendant

Tags: codenameone

I'd like derive a class from Button to add an initial delay and interval which shall be used as long as the button is touched for repeated action.

At first thought this seems to be simple enough but the method `com.codename1.ui.Button.setState(int)` cannot be overridden because it has package access only. Is that for a good reason?

I noticed, that Button calls actionPerformed on pointerReleased. My Button descendant should call actionPerformed repeatedly but not wen the parent container of the Button is beeing scrolled. This would hopefully just correspond with the Button state STATE_PRESSED, right?

Comment: I don't understand what sort of UI you are trying to create? Are you trying to create a toggle button? The `setState` method is internal because it's states are intended for UI interactions in non-touch devices e.g. rollover which makes no sense in touch devices.

Comment: What I am trying to do - and I did it by overriding getX() and using getState() and a Timer - is repeated action whilst the Button is kept depressed. And I disagree - the pressed state is used on touch devices as well

Comment: Sorry, I meant to say "**some** of it's states are..."

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly what you mean then I'd just start a timer on the `pressed` method and then repeatedly call `super.pressed` & `super.released` whenever the timer elapses.

Comment: I want some Buttons to act like keys on a pc keyboard. For that I need to know when my Button descendant is pressed. Then I create a Timer with a given initial delay and a given interval which fires the Button action. When the Button is released I cancel the Timer.

Comment: Yes, that was clearer. This is what I was answering.